# Is there any way to send parameters from one page to another page without sending them in url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Is there any way to send parameters from one page to other page without binding them in the URL. In most of the cases we send the values in the URL for retrieving those values on the next page. Like in AngularJs:

```
 <li ng-repeat="cat in x.Child"><a ng-href="#/ProductListingByCategory/{{cat.Id}}">{{cat.Name}}</a></li>
```

In Javascript or Jquery we do like this.

```
<li><a href='Product/ProductList/" + this.Id + "'>" + this.Name + </a> </li>
```

Is there any alternate solution to this that we should not send parameters in the URL? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can set your parameter in local storage and get them in another page.

Comment: I noticed one of your tags is asp.net-mvc. why not just put them in the viewbag?

Comment: you may choose local storge,or constants

Comment: @Bryan dellinger what if i'm using api to fetch data and show api data on page.

Comment: do you mean asp.net web api?  if so then your typically make an ajax call to your controller that returns your data in JSON. then on success of the ajax call you have what you need. (and by controller I mean the web api controller )

Comment: no angularjs controller.

Comment: If you are not letting the "id" in the url, the user cant put a bookmark on the page to come back later (or using the back button on his navigator). So here's my question : This is what you want ?

Comment: Is this a security thing - is it sensitive data you dont want to send via the querystring?

Comment: Yes @Jamiec it could be sensitive data. for security reasons i'm asking.

Comment: @SaqibMajeed - security is not *just* about obscuring the values. There is nothing *inherantly* wrong with pasing data via a URL, so long as you're authorizing on the server-side to stop url hacking. Often these values are instead sent via a POST body, but this merely makes it a tiny bit harder to hack - in either case you must validate all data passed between pages.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `ui-router`, you can do this using the params property of a state.

```
$stateProvider.state('state.name', {
    url: "/state-url",
    params: {
        myParam: null
    }
});
```

When you are transitioning to the state, you can assign the `myParam` any value you want and you will then be able to access it through `$stateParams`.

**Usage in View**

```
<a ui-sref="state.name({ myParam: 'Value of the param' })">Link Text</a>
```

**Usage in Controller**

```
$state.go('state.name', {
    myParam: 'Value of the param'
});
```

Just be aware that after a page reload, those parameters will be empty, because they are stored just in memory.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in few ways and localStorage is a common way to do it.

Example: In Controller A, you can set the value of the variable to a name using localStorage

```
$scope.age = 50;
localStorage.setItem('age', $scope.age);
```

In Controller B or anywhere outside, you can fetch it using the getItem.

```
var age = localStorage.getItem('age');
```